# How can I get registered users in a Telegram Bot using the API

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm writing a bot for telegram. I'm wondering what if I loose the `user_id` and the corresponding `chat_id` of registered users of my bot.

Is there anyway to ask telegram bot, which users or chats are joined to the bot? I didn't find any clue in the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to log yourself, I asked @BotSupport same question too, seems Telegram won't make this API.